# Returning an incorrect variable from method

Tags: python, class, matplotlib

I am obtaining a wired behavior when I try to return an array from a method, here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

class ClickAndRoi:
    def __init__(self, fig = [], ax = []):

        self.selected_pixel = []              
        if fig == []:
            fig = plt.gcf()
        if ax == []:
            ax = plt.gca()

        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = ax
        self._ID1 = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._onclick)
        plt.waitforbuttonpress()

        if sys.flags.interactive:
            plt.show(block=False)
        else:
            plt.show()

    def _onclick(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            self.selected_pixel = [x, y]
            self.ax.scatter(self.selected_pixel[0],
                            self.selected_pixel[1],
                            s=5,
                            c='red',
                            marker='o')
            plt.draw()
            if sys.flags.interactive:
                pass
            else:        
                plt.close(self.fig)
            pass              

    def createROI(self, currentImage, PETSlice):
        print(self.selected_pixel)
        circle_masked_Im = currentImage[:, :, PETSlice]
        nx, ny = np.shape(circle_masked_Im)
        cordx, cordy = np.ogrid[0:nx, 0:ny]
        circle_mask = ((cordx - self.selected_pixel[1])**2 +
                        (cordy - self.selected_pixel[0])**2 <  10)
        circle_masked_Im[circle_mask] = 0

        return currentImage
```

And here how I call it:

```
plt.imshow(Current_Image[:, :, 50])    #50 is the slice of the 3d image
myROI = ClickAndRoi()

segemented_Image = myROI.createROI(SUV, 50) #50 is the slice of the 3d image

plt.close()
plt.imshow(segemented_Image[:,:, 50])
```

The objective of the class is to click a point in a 3d image slice (`np.array`) and based in this position segment the image via threshold.

The strange behaviour comes on the method `createROI`. As its written now, in theory, should take the `currentImage` and return the `currentImage`, but, instead of that, it returns `circle_masked_Im`!!

Why this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: May I see initalisation of `SUV` and `print(type(SUV))`.

Comment: This are the results: `>>> print(type(SUV))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem based on the answers posted in [Python: unwanted change of variable occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917301/python-unwanted-change-of-variable-occurs) .

The problems seems to be that variables in Python are references and not values. Using deepcopy solved the problem:

```
fom copy importy deepcopy
```

and assign the variable as

```
circle_masked_Im = deepcopy(currentImage[:, :, PETSlice])
```

Probably there is a more elegant way to solve the problem, but this just works fine.